# Express Body Parser with Custom Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am in the middle of setting up a REST API that takes requests with a custom Content-Type, but I am having trouble parsing the body with the NPM package body-parser. I am running some tests with Mocha and Chai-HTTP and seding my request tests like this:

```
chai.request(server)
.post('/demo')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd+companyName.v01+json')
.send({name: 'test'})
.end(function(err, res) {/* tests are here */});
```

In my express app's app.js, I am calling this middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/*+json'}));
```

When I make the type more general, like making it 'application/*', I can pass the request through with a 'application/json' Content-Type, but not my custom one. When I do this, my req.body is an empty object. If bodyParser was just completely not working, req.body would be undefined and not an empty object. By looking at the docs, I feel like my options on my bodyParser call are correct, but clearly not - any insight?

Comment: You're not describing what you mean by _"trouble parsing the body"_.

Comment: Sorry. I mean that once I get through my middleware and to my route, req.body is an empty object.

Comment: Hmm yeah I can reproduce the issue. Let me check...

Comment: Thanks, let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vnd+companyName.v01+json` isn't a valid media type.

A valid media type should look like:

```
[ tree. ] subtype name [ +suffix ] [ ; parameters ]
```

The subtype name can't contain `.` or `+` characters, those are reserved for the (optional) *tree* and *suffix*, respectively ([RFC6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838)).

So in your case, the mime type should look like this:

```
application/vnd.companyName-v01+json
```

However, it seems that there's an additional requirement imposed by `body-parser` (or rather, [`type-is`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-is), which is used to match content type), in that the subtype name needs to be lower case:

```
application/vnd.companyname-v01+json
```

Strangely, that requirement only applies for the `body-parser` configuration part, the client is allowed to use upper case in its requests.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the heads up. This solved my issue.

Comment: Where do you see that [type-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-is) requires lower case subtypes? I dug through the source and it didn't pop out at me immediately. I am going to open a pull request on the docs for [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to clarify that.

Comment: Oh that's just discovery-by-experimentation. It wasn't matching when the server was configured with upper case characters, but it was matching when I lower cased those.